What should I do if a new Staging Ground item already has the same comment I would make (with no review action)?
I came across this question (deleted now: here is a screenshot) in staging ground that is flagged as new and offering me the same options as any other new questions. I want to review it as "require major changes", but another user already left the same comment I was going to make. I would agree with the comment and leave my review, but reviews requesting edits require a recent comment. Should I make the same comment as the other user in my own words? Should I say "I agree" to the other comment? Should I just skip the question?

Well, there is "always" stg to add in your own Comment, when some previous Reviewer already left a Comment, but forgot to cast their Review... In this case, you can point the User to the [tour] + the [ask] Help-page, and some [javascript] Tag also needs to be added. (And 'Stack Snippets' are not supported in the 'SG'...)

If the reviewer does not request "Needs Major Changes" and that is, in fact, what is needed, then I will simply make the same comment but request major changes.

It is not always bad to repeat a comment. It might break through the stubbornness of people when they get the same message from multiple sources. I wouldn't ever let the existence of comments be a block for you to make the right curation decisions in any case, that would be a complete system failure.

Related: It should be possible to require major changes based on someone else's comment

Ideally, you do not need to do much. You can upvote the comment. Or you can comment yourself but I would avoid that if it is superfluous.
However, in the case you showed - there is actual merit of leaving a comment.

The reviewer did not choose Major Changes feedback, even though they left a comment requesting them. Without a review action, the post will just automatically move to the main site. Despite the fact that there is a comment asking for a minimal reproducible example, the only thing the system looks at are the review actions.
When somebody has left a comment suitable for Major Changes but has not left that feedback, you can just reply to them with something like "Yes, please do that" (or something more substantial if you can add more) and choose Major Changes yourself.

The reviewer asked for a Stack Snippet. However, the editor used in Staging Ground does not support Stack Snippets. This request can be confusing and generally generate chatter ("How do I do this" -> "You press the button" -> "There is no button", and so on) that is basically a waste of time.


I elected to leave the canned comment requesting an MRE and left a Major Changes as review action for this particular post.

It would also be possible to ask the first reviewer to use "Requires Major Changes" in the future in a response to their comment, e.g. Thank you for taking the time to provide feedback to askers. In the future, would it be possible to use the "Requires Major Changes" option when asking for clarification from the author? See also the [Reviewer Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/staging-ground-reviewer-guidelines).

@dan1st see also the template I proposed in the comments on the community guide.

Answer is a bit flawed because based on incomplete Qt. OP asked this current Qt because they encountered a Qt in 'SG' with Status=New, which to their surprise already had a Comment from a Reviewer, heading to Require Majors Changes, but the Reviewer had forgotten to cast their Review. => No Reviewer needs to post the same Comment otherwise... => "You can upvote the comment. Or you can comment yourself but I would avoid that if it is superfluous." is not correct: Upvoting the previous Comment (without posting some own Comment) will not bypass the "Comment required" for a Review.

@chivracq This is addressed in the answer. After the first paragraph.

Yep, that's what I mean, the first paragraph will never be invoked... (Because the conditions will never be met/happen...) // Asker in 'SG' deleted their Qt btw "in the few hours", I still have it open in some Tab, in case abd wants a Screenshot.. (Not sure if >20k-Users have access to 'SG'-Deleted Qt's..?)

@chivracq The first paragraph is the general case. The rest is the exception for this particular case - when somebody left a comment you wanted to make but hasn't used the appropriate Major Changes review. Because in that case somebody has to leave a Major Changes review and for that you need to comment. Otherwise you don't.

If needed, I took a Screenshot of the original Qt in the 'SG' (now deleted)... (If >10k/20k-Users have access to deleted Qt's in the 'SG', they'll be able to provide a "better" Screenshot...)

@VLAZ "The first paragraph is the general case.", beh no, sorry, we are talking about a 'SG'-Qt in New Status because the (first)  Reviewer forgot to cast their Review. // But 3rd time I try to explain, apparently to no avail, I guess we are all wasting our time, your Answer is gathering UV's, the 'Meta'-Crowd is apparently happy.. => All is well...

@chivracq the  followed by  I considered a fairly well-known formula that I have applied in other answers and have seen applied by others (on- and off-site). So, I'm not sure what needs to be changed or clarified here. Seems like I'd be adding fluff if I try to clarify that the first paragraph is not what should be done here. Because the rest of the post does say that it's specific to the SG item that was used as example.

There have been times I've come across SG posts that a previous reviewer has left only a comment, or possibly a marked status that was not "requires major changes", where I felt the post did necessarily require significant edits from the OP.

Keep it in mind that this is your review of the post. Your suggestions. It's ok if your review covers some or all of the same points as someone else's review. SG comments are threaded so it's easy to track what conversations are going on.

If your comment is similar but you've some additional information, suggestion, or just want to concur with the existing comments, then please do leave an additional comment stating such, and update the post status to "requires major changes".

If your comment is identical to existing comment(s) and you've nothing further to add, then still leave a comment and update the post status to "requires major changes". You can optionally delete your duplicate comment if you truly feel it noisy or redundant/unnecessary to re-iterate suggestions to the OP.


